# Which Golarion deities would support and encourage a Witch-Hunter Inquisitor among their faithful?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, religions-and-deities, golarion

I'm putting together a Witch Hunter Inquisitor with the Black Powder Inquisition for an Adventure Path campaign, but I'm not quite sure which gods would be particularly interested in counting a zealous opponent of 'black magic and foul sorcery' (defined *much* more broadly than is the norm around Golarion...) within their ranks? Even better if it's a deity for whom Black Powder makes sense as well, though I suspect I can justify that under any faith with some biographical gymnastics.

**Edit:** I guess I wasn't sufficiently clear; what throws me is trying to design a character who is inherently suspicious and distrustful of the arcane in broad strokes, while still being tied to the worship of one of the deities in a world which is *so thoroughly magical*. None of them really scream out as being particularly good places for 'militant suspicion' in quite the same way as, say... the Faerunian Triad could. I'm looking for a deity where it'd be perfectly normal for a devout follower to vaguely acknowledge that there *might* **somewhere** in the world, be a wizard who isn't evil... but doubts it.

What faith would a character like this most likely find themselves enmeshed in?

Comment: That's still not very clear. So are you looking for a good god? Or any god that's against arcane magic? What location (there's a lot of Asian gods that won't make a lot of sense in Varisia)? What AP? There's a lord of Abaddon that has gunpowder in his portfolio, is that on target? Please help us help you by giving more context. Including empyreal lords and loa and whatnot there's hundreds of extant Golarion deities.

Comment: Part of the problem is that *I'm* not entirely sure. :P Waiting on the DM to make up his mind between Reign of Winter, Iron Gods, and Wrath of the Righteous. As for alignment, I'm comfortable working with any non-evil generally.

Comment: What would your character do if another character in the party is a sorcerer?  Being against arcane magic in any form (which is how I read your question) is reasonable, so long as everyone else you'll be playing with is on board with it.

Comment: Not trust him until he earns it; it's really no different from the paladin being in a party with a thief -- a delicate, but by no means intractable situation.

Answer (score 4):

One would think any good (and frankly even many Neutral) gods would have a place for opposition of black magic and foul sorcery.  That's kinda like saying "who doesn't like murderers?" "Anyone but Norgorberites I guess?" is the answer. Even CN churches won't like it if there's enslaving/domination going on from the baddies.

Good type gods that are the *most* martial are Iomedae and Sarenrae. Gods with more of a craftsman aspect that might be Black Powder friendly are Torag and Abadar.

You'd do better to include what AP you're playing in and what kind of character you'd like to be like beyond the class details to get a more helpful answer. What part of Golarion? What kind of bad guys? If the answer is "necromancers" then suddenly Pharasma jumps up pretty highly in the choices, for example.

If you'd like a "Conan the savage who doesn't like arcane magic" feel, then the Kellid race and Gorum as a deity makes a lot of sense. Kellids from Numeria get some gun contact and would work very well for Reign of Winter (they hate White Witches), Iron Gods (from the area), and Wrath of the Righteous (from the area).